# changing in apache mpm prefork to mpm event and did not show the page

Tags: apache, centos7

Im trying to use mpm event for a website that has a lot of request at the same time.
changing the configuration in apache produced an error and the page is not displayed
On centos 7 and Apache 2.4 installed

change the configuracion /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

1-uncomment

LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so

2- then restart server

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

3- Add this configuration on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers 3
    MinSpareThreads          25
    MaxSpareThreads          75
    ThreadLimit                      64
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxRequestWorkers    30
    MaxConnectionsPerChild    1000
</IfModule>
```

Is missing some configuration or installation of a module for php for MPM EVENT to work?

Comment: Did you comment the `mpm_prefork_module` line? Apache wouldn't appreciate using two forking models at the same time.

Comment: yes.. the mpm_prefork_module is commented.. i have to configure Vhost? give this error: [Mon Jun 24 10:10:47.627545 2019] [:error] [pid 13425] Misconfiguration of certificate's CN and virtual name.

Comment: Did you see that? https://serverfault.com/questions/877544/httpd-misconfiguration-of-certificates-cn-and-virtual-name

Comment: i dont have that file openstack